# get a list of numbers and check if there is a Middle- Peak in it -Python

Tags: python

Im lerning python for beginners and have a task that called "Middle-Peak list"
which means that I'm getting a list of numbers and need to search if the num in the middle is bigger than all numbers before him and after him.

for example if the list is 1 3 5 2 1
so need to print ("A Middle-Peak list") -- num 5 is the middle index.

I'm getting some errors so appreciate your help.

```
mylist=[int(i) for i in input("Enter a list of numbers: ").split()]

mid=int(len(mylist)/2)

for i in mylist:
    if I[0:mid]<i[mid] and i[mid:]<i[mid]:
        print("A Middle-Peak list")
    else:
        print("NOT A Middle-Peak list")
```

Comment: what would happen if your data has an even length?

Comment: should the left hand side and right hand site of your peak be ordered?

Comment: something like that [1,2,3,10,8,4,2] like should it look like a mountain in real life or it could be [1,2,3,4,10,5,4,5,3]

Comment: because for the first input, we should see if 10 is a peak and see if the left hand side is ordered increasingly and right hand side ordered decreasingly.

Comment: I forgot to mention- the numbers before the middle are growing and after the middle reducing

Comment: yes i knew it... lol

Answer (score 0):

1. You should test for an odd number of input numbers of at least length 3.
2. You also have a misspelled variable, `I` and assorted other logical issues.

```
while True:
    mylist = [int(i) for i in input("Enter a list of numbers: ").split()]
    n = len(mylist)
    if n % 2 == 1 and n >= 3:
        break
    print("The list should have an odd number of elements and be at least 3 elements long.")
mid = n // 2  # integer division
mid_elem = mylist[mid]
success = True
for i, elem in enumerate(mylist):
    if i != mid and elem >= mid_elem:
        success = False
        break
print( "A Midlle-Peak list" if success else "NOT A Middle-Peak list")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input will ever be list with odd number of digits:

```
# gets the numbers list
numbers = input("Enter a list of numbers: ")
numbers = [int(number) for number in numbers]

# gets the index of the highest number:
highest_number_index = numbers.index(max(numbers))

# checks if it is the middle digit
if highest_number_index + 1 == (len(numbers) + 1) / 2:
    print("A Middle-Peak list")
else:
    print("NOT A Middle-Peak list")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data can have an  even length I would try something like this:

```
mylist=[int(i) for i in input("Enter a list of numbers: ").split()]

mid_index=int(len(mylist)/2) - 1
mid_value = mylist[mid_index]
is_mid_peak = True
current_index = 0

for i in mylist:
   if i >= mid_value and current_index != mid_index:
       is_mid_peak = False
       break
   current_index += 1

if is_mid_peak:
    print("A Middle-Peak list")
else:
    print("NOT A Middle-Peak list")
```

**EDIT:**
Based on your comment

```
mylist=[int(i) for i in input("Enter a list of numbers: ").split()]

mid_index=int(len(mylist)/2) - 1

first_half = mylist[:mid_index]
scond_half = mylist[mid_index:]

is_growing = all(first_half[i] < first_half[i+1] for i in range(len(first_half)-1))
is_reducing = all(scond_half[i] > scond_half[i+1] for i in range(len(scond_half)-1))

if is_growing and is_reducing:
    print("A Middle-Peak list")
else:
    print("NOT A Middle-Peak list")
```

Comment: I forgot to mention- the numbers before the middle are growing and after the middle reducing

Comment: But you have to check if this condition is true, or you just assume that it is always true?

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,8,1,2,1,0]

peak = list1[int(len(list1)/2)]

def peak(list1):
    for i in range(len(list1)-1):
        if i<int(len(list1)/2):
            print(i)
            if list1[i+1]<list1[i]:
                return "Not Peak1"
        elif i>=int(len(list1)/2):
            print(i)
            if list1[i]<list1[i+1]:
                return "Not Peak2"
    return "Peak"
```

This should work for odd lengths for lists. Naming peaks differently will help identify where the code is not working. Printing `i` also helps identify where the issue happened.